# Событие срабатывает только при втором клике jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Взял логику многоязычности [с этого сайта.](https://lang.dev2studio.com/)

Короче есть ссылка с атрибутом `onclick`. Она передает параметр в следующий код и тем самым включая нужный язык:

```
<a class="langswtch" onclick="setLang('en')"><img class="lang" src="images/langen.png"></a>
<a class="langswtch" onclick="setLang('de')"><img class="lang" src="images/langde.png"></a>
<a class="langswtch" onclick="setLang('ru')"><img class="lang" src="images/langru.png"></a>
```

```
function setLang(setLang){
   $('body').data('lang-active',setLang);
   lang('lang','data-lang','body');
};
```

Но так же у меня есть `input` куда через `data-lang` передается значение из конфига переводов.

```
<input type="hidden" class="inputtext" data-lang="house"></input>
<img class="house" src="">
```

Потом через следующий скрипт у меня значение из input передается в атрибут `src` тега `img`:

```
   $input = $('input.inputtext').text();
   $img = $('img.house');
   $img.attr('src', $input);
```

Но прикол в том, что при нажатии на кнопку передается значение в `input` с этим же кликом это значение должно передаться в src, но т.к. это происходит в одном клике, как я понял, то при первом клике всегда передается старое значение, и только при втором новое.

```
function setLang(setLang){
   $('body').data('lang-active',setLang);
   lang('lang','data-lang','body');
   $input = $('input.inputtext').text();
   $img = $('img.house');
   $img.attr('src', $input);
};
```

Вот это как то нужно пофиксить, не знаю как. Может кто что то подсказать?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вы или добавьте песочницу, либо объясните как работает вот это: `lang('lang','data-lang','body');` и по какому принципу в `input` меняется значение.

Comment: @DiD, я добавил ссылку на сайт, откуда взял логику многоязычности, там описано все как работает, если надо могу в вопрос перенести.
Единственное, функционал с input я не оттуда взял. Благодаря скрипту с того сайта, у меня в инпуте из конфига с переводами (с помощью data-lang) возвращается значение, а потом скриптом (который есть в вопросе) оно переносится в src.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не достаточно информации, вы не привели пример функции lang() {...} Поэтому логика неясна.

Но из примера выше видно, что вы пытаетесь взять значение input некорректно. Используйте следующий код:

```
let value = $('input.inputtext').val();
```

Так же подозреваю, что при обновлении значение в этом инпуте нужно использовать что то типа:

```
$('input.inputtext').val(newValue).change();
```

То есть, не только установить новое значение, но и вызвать событие change() по которому в коде вы сможете слушать это событие например вот так:

```
$('input.inputtext').on("change", function(event){
  // какая то ваша логика
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Хороший способ. Но я воспользовался другой библиотекой и для подгрузки новой картинки использовал ajax, я должен был закрыть этот вопрос, но что то забыл.